# Пропорциональный resize изображения при загрузки laravel

Tags: php, laravel, resize

Возможно ли стандартными методами laravel, без сторонних библиотек, пропорционально уменьшить размер изображения?
Мой способ загрузки изображения на сервер

```
$path = $request->file('image')->store('uploads','public');
```

Если кому интересно как я сделал:

Использовал [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/)

```
    $file = $request->file('image');

    //get filename with extension
    $filenamewithextension = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    //get filename without extension
    $filename = pathinfo($filenamewithextension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    //get file extension
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    //filename to store
    $filenametostore = $filename.'_'.uniqid().'.'.$extension;

    \Storage::put('public/profile_images/'. $filenametostore, fopen($file, 'r+'));

    //Resize image here
    $thumbnailpath = public_path('storage/profile_images/'.$filenametostore);
    $img = Image::make($thumbnailpath);
    $height = $img->height();
    $width = $img->width();
    if($height >= 601) {
        $img->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });
    }
    if($width >= 601) {
        $img->resize(null, 300, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });
    }
    $img->save($thumbnailpath);
```

Comment: ответ тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627476/php-resize-image-proportionally-with-max-width-or-weight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, сделайте по такому примеру:
используйте Image:
    use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

в коде

```
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg')
// resize the image to a width of 300 and constrain aspect ratio (auto height)
$img->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
```